# RouteLink parameters in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I have his route defined in app.module

```
{path:'empleados/:año/:mes', component:ListaEmpleadosComponent},
```

Then in my app.component.ts that bootstrap the application I have this

```
export class AppComponent {
tituloPagina = 'Parte de Horas';
fechaActual:Date=new Date();
mesActual:number=this.fechaActual.getMonth();
añoActual:number=this.fechaActual.getFullYear();
}
```

And the template associated: app.component.html

```html
<nav class='navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light'>
    <a class='navbar-brand'>{{tituloPagina}}</a>
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
      <li><a class='nav-link' [routerLink]="['welcome']">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class='nav-link' 
      [routerLink]="['/empleados',{{añoActual}},  {{mesActual}}]">Empleados</a></li>
      <label>{{fechaActual}}</label>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class='container'>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

But I get this error
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 20 in [[/empleados/datos/',{{añoActual}}, {{mesActual}}]] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@5:30 (

Any idea please?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong you should pass variable without the quote like this

```
[routerLink]="['/empleados', añoActual,  mesActual]"
```

But I would recommend you change your variable `añoActual` to become alphabet variable witout having speacial character

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the route parameters like this,

```
<a class='nav-link' 
  [routerLink]="['/empleados', añoActual, mesActual]">Empleados</a>
```

Don't analyze the URL. Let the router do it.
The router extracts the route parameters from the URL and supplies it to the ListaEmpleadosComponent via the ActivatedRoute service.

The router composes the destination URL from the array like this: localhost:4200/empleados/x/y.

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-the-route-parameters-in-the-list-view

Comment: In my case this code is in app.component.html and I don't get the values from any url loaded previously. I need to set the url in this <a> element using values calculated in app.component.ts. And I don't know how to pass these values to the template if not by interpolation but this does not work. Your solution gets me the same error. Thanks

Comment: You can just create accordingly named variables in app.component.ts file. Angular router will retrieve those variable values and prepare the URL by itself.

Comment: In the app.component.ts file just declare the variables.
`añoActual: string = "somestring";
mesActual: string = "someotherstring";`  

There is no need for interpolation.  If it still doesn't work try using standard ASCII characters for variable name.

Comment: Great works fine the problem was the "ñ" character. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help! Accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[routerLink]="['/empleados', {añoActual:añoActual ,  mesActual: mesActual}]"
```

You will receive it in the routed component from activated route param as as JSON object you can parse it and use further.

Comment: In my case this code is in app.component.html and I don't get the values from any url loaded previously. I need to set the url in this <a> element using values calculated in app.component.ts. And I don't know how to pass these values to the template if not by interpolation but this does not work. Your solution gets me the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the name of the variable "añoActual" If I use actualYear this code works fine

```
<li><a class='nav-link' 
[routerLink]="['/empleados',actualYear, actualMonth]">Empleados</a></li>
```